# Pack expansion failure with g++ 4.9.0, but works with clang++ 3.4

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

For the code below:

```
template <typename... Ts>
struct Set {};

template <typename T, typename... Ts>
using Tail = Set<Ts...>;

template <typename T, typename TS>
struct MemberOf;

template <typename T, typename... Ts>
struct MemberOf<T, Set<T, Ts...>> {
    static constexpr bool value = true;
};

template <typename T>
struct MemberOf<T, Set<>> {
    static constexpr bool value = false;
};

template <typename T, typename... Ts>
struct MemberOf<T, Set<Ts...>> {
    static constexpr bool value = false || MemberOf<T, Tail<Ts...>>::value;
};
```

g++ 4.9.0 gives:

```
ts.cpp:27:63: error: pack expansion argument for non-pack parameter 'T' of alias template 'template<class T, class ... Ts> using Tail = Set<Ts ...>'
     static constexpr bool value = false || MemberOf<T, Tail<Ts...>>::value;
                                                               ^
ts.cpp:4:11: note: declared here
 template <typename T, typename... Ts>
           ^
ts.cpp:27:66: error: template argument 2 is invalid
     static constexpr bool value = false || MemberOf<T, Tail<Ts...>>::value;
                                                                  ^
```

clang++ 3.4 compiles it without any diagnostic. It looks like a g++ bug to me, but just wanted to confirm.

ADDENDUM: So, based on the great answers below, the problem seems to be that a pack argument must correspond exactly to a pack parameter in an alias template. In other words:

```
template <typename T, typename... Ts>
using Tail = Set<Ts...>;

template <typename... Ts>
using Alias1 = Tail<Ts...>; // ERROR, Ts doesn't correspond directly to the pack in Tail.

template <typename... Ts>
using Alias2 = Tail<int, Ts...>; // Okay, now it does.
```

Comment: Have you [tried this as a work-around](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3cfefebf9556f603) ?

Comment: Another workaround is to [replace the template alias `Tail` with a template class](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fd480f791c905b20).

Comment: @WhozCraig: That looks good, and is arguably simpler. I'd still like to know though what's going on with the alias. I'll look hvd's answer in more depth in a few hours.

Comment: Yet another workaround is to use a [combination of class template and alias template](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2f344340c46f9340), so you can still write `Tail<Ts...>` instead of `typename Tail<Ts...>::type`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Newer versions of clang now reject your code as well, due to the fix for the following bug:

http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=18401

Richard Smith's comment on the fix is:

> Fix assert by implementing the current proposed direction of core
>   issue 1430. Don't allow a pack expansion to be used as an argument to an alias
>   template unless the corresponding parameter is a parameter pack.

The referenced [core defect](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1430) includes, as an example, code which is essentially identical to yours:

```
template<class... x> class list{};
template<class a, class... b> using tail=list<b...>;
template <class...T> void f(tail<T...>);

int main() {
  f<int,int>({});
}
```

And the defect notes:

> There is implementation variance in the handling of this example.

The earlier example given by the defect is a more difficult case that seems to require templates aliases to not behave as transparent aliases for templates. Because of this implementation issue the committee is apparently leaning toward prohibiting using template aliases in certain ways, and compilers implementers seem to be going with that solution.

So my understanding is that this code is valid under the current spec as written, but there are implementation problems and the committee may eventually prohibit it.

Comment: However, the latest clang (well, 16th of April version at least) is also complaining about pack expansion of non-pack parameter, so I'm not convinced. g++ 4.8.2 is giving a different error. I'm fetching latest clang right now, to see what that's like.

Comment: @MatsPetersson Thanks for pointing that out. That lead me to what I think is the real issue.

Comment: Interesting, though I don't completely understand why it creates an implementation problem. The compiler has both the alias expansion and all template arguments at instantiation time, so it seems that it could just resolve it then. I noticed the defect issue says that somehow this would require mangling, but I don't know why that would be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

The use of a template alias is supposed to be such that the alias can be expanded where it is used.

After your definition of

```
template <typename T, typename... Ts>
using Tail = Set<Ts...>;
```

you use

```
Tail<Ts...>
```

but this cannot be replaced by anything involving `Set<...>`.

(I must admit I'm having trouble finding a reference to support this interpretation, so I don't know for sure if this is what the standard states, or merely what compilers implement.)

Comment: Yeah, I don't quite understand this either. If I expand a parameter pack `Xs...` and pass it to a template alias taking `<T, Ts...>` my understanding is that the first item in `Xs` is bound to `T` and the rest of the pack is bound to `Ts`. Passing an expanded parameter pack is supposed to behave like passing the individual items of the pack.

Comment: @bames53 But you get the error even if you don't instantiate the template. The error is at template definition time, and at that point, there is no "first item in `Xs`".

Comment: But since there's a valid template instantiation it can't be rejected at the time of the template definition. Anyway I believe I've uncovered the underlying issue in my answer.

Comment: @bames53 My answer is the same as yours, except you found the official support for it. The alias gets expanded where it is used, which is in the template definition, and at that point there is no way to expand the alias.